# Validating Birthday with express validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

```
check('birthday').isDate({format:"YYYY-MM-DD"}).custom((value)=>{
      var dob = new Date(value)
      var year = dob.getFullYear()
      var today = new Date();
      var age = today.getFullYear() - year
      if (age < 18){
        throw new Error('Your age should be 18+')
      }
 
    })
```

if I enter a birthdate that is less than 18 then it will show an error 'Your age should be 18+', but when I give any other date then it shows an error like this

```
{"errors":[{"value":"2000-06-05","msg":"Invalid value","param":"birthday","location":"body"}]}
```

can anyone tell me what the problem is

Comment: You need to return a `true` value in success cases from the `custom` validator function. Add `return true;` after the `if` block.